# Unable to launch iOS app on simulator using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to develop an iOS app that I'm attempting to run on the simulator.  The simulator apparently loads and runs but never completes or loads the app.

Screen shot:

[image: The simulator loads but apparently never completes or loads the app.]

This is what I get, there are no error messages of any kind.  Anyone know whats going on here?

More information:
I do see this in the Xamarin output window
`Authentication Error. Xcode 7.3 or later is required to continue developing with your Apple ID.`

I'm using XCode 13.3 so I have no idea why I would be seeing this message.

Comment: is the same version of Xamairn installed on both the PC and Mac?

Comment: Yes, both machines are updated to the latest version, v15.6.0.3 on the Mac, same on VS 2022.

Comment: @Jason Apparently this is a know issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-load-apple-certificates/1692185, they're working on a fix.

Comment: @PrescottChartier You could also post this in issue on GitHub for double check. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: @Wendy Zang I do not believe this is a Xamarin Forms issue.

Comment: Let's waiting for this known issue to be fixed in the future.

Comment: Running the iOS 15.4 emulators currently work on Visual Studio for Mac. Even after, updating Xcode to v. 13.3 and macOs to v. Monterey 12.3

Comment: Yes, I was able to use the simulator on the Mac using Visual Studio 2019 for the Mac.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Latest xcode (13.3) running on my mac (12.3 Monterey). Latest version of VS2022 Preview 14 (17.2, Preview 2.1)

Comment: I also have the same issue after updating to VS 17.1.3. I've reported it to Microsoft [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-iOS-Simulator-broken-black-scre/10004291?space=8&scope=follow).  Amazingly, that same update broke Hot Restart, which is needed to test on a real device, meaning it's currently literally impossible to develop for Xamarin iOS.  Neat.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with simulators but I don't think I'm getting that same error message. Is everyone getting that same error message?

Comment: @Wade Baird I don't believe the error message I'm getting has anything to do with the simulator issue.

Comment: It is unfortunate as I had updated to 17.1.3 two days ago, it gave me a warning about needing XCode 13.3 else it's has unknown results. My Mac can't upgrade to Monterey, so I went out and bought a new Mac to upgrade to 13.3... and it turns out I probably didn't need to.

Comment: If you hit Tools, iOS, open terminal on paired mac... you will most likely see this:

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly ‘CLAP, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’ or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044) at Xamarin.Messaging.Terminal.Program.Main(String[] args)     but I haven't seen any responses from MS about a fix release date -- and I'm currently struggling to find a workaround with no luck for days.